# How to generate BigInteger.probablePrime randomly in android?

Tags: java, android, rsa

I'm using this code, I tried in netbean can run well, but when I tried in eclipse for android project it doesn't work. I want to get public Key randomly, but the result is always "35879".

```
    publicKey = BigInteger.probablePrime(10, new Random());

    while (phi.gcd(publicKey).compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) > 0 && publicKey.compareTo(phi) < 0 ) {  
       publicKey.add(BigInteger.ONE);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and use more than 10 bits. Or, for the public exponent, simply use 65537, the fourth number of Fermat.

When generating random numbers for cryptography (or security in general), always use `SecureRandom` - never *instantiate* `Random`.